# Check if rectangle contains cursor

Tags: vb.net, contains

In the paint event of my code, I'm trying to show one image if the cursor is hovering over the rectangle but show another if it's not.

```
If rectangle.contains(cursor.position) Then
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.image_hover, rectangle)
Else
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.image, rectangle)
End If
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes,  `Screen.Position: A System.Drawing.Point that represents the cursor's position in screen coordinates.`  Intellisense is your friend

Comment: Couldn't you just handle the `MouseEnter`/`MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events?